# Regex to validate a network path it PHP, jQuery, JavaScript, Ruby

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ruby, regex

Trying to figure out a regex for validating a network path ie: `\\comp\xyz` or `\\comp` or `\\comp\x\y\z\storage` or something much more lengthy on all parts but the jist of it is hopefully conveyed.

What I have currently is a simple input field, that I have a user passing information through. Thing of it is I don't want them to put it in wrong as the backend connects to a client that uses it to run processes on computers across a network, so last thing I need is someone mistyping something and being the cause of something else breaking. So I figure a quick preg_match will do me just fine in confirming this from the PHP side I am currently work with but I do have a need to work this into JavaScript and a layer thats built on Ruby so I not knowing if all regex is equal or not I need one that works on all levels..

Also to save me time later in coming back I will eventually need to figure out a regex that will allow a user to do either local path ie: `C:\`, `X:`, `H:\path\to\folder` or a network path as mentioned prior.

Comment: I'm certain that PHP and Javascript use PCRE. I'd be surprised if Ruby doesn't as well.

Comment: As a tip I would recommend you free tool for regular expresions: [Espresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/ExpressoDownload.htm)

Comment: I think PCRE supports lookbehind, and JavaScript does not (???)

Comment: @Cfreak, What do you mean by "using PCRE"?  PHP farms out its regex handling to the PCRE library, but JavaScript doesn't.  If you just mean a flavor that's derived from Perl's, call it just that: Perl-derived.  "PCRE" is hopelessly ambiguous.  As for Ruby, yes it's another Perl-derived flavor, but its actual regex support is provided by the Oniguruma library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\\comp\x\y\z\storage`:

```
/^\\(\\[^\s\\]+)+(\\)?$/
```

`H:\path\to\folder`:

```
/^([A-Za-z]:(\\)?|[A-Za-z]:(\\[^\s\\]+)+)(\\)?$/
```

`Both`:

```
/^(\\(\\[^\s\\]+)+|([A-Za-z]:(\\)?|[A-z]:(\\[^\s\\]+)+))(\\)?$/
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/gLfdv/

Comment: matches `\\\\\\\\\\comp\x\y\z\\\\\\\\storage` - was this intended? (is this valid path? - I only know regex pretty well, not network paths as well, I guess)

Comment: only one character between each slash? (for the network path)

Comment: I was about to say it didn't match `X:`, but then you fixed that -- of course, unless I miss my guess, it now doesn't match `C:\` - oh wait - there you go (don't forget the "both" expression, though)

Comment: It matches `C:` - `/^([A-z]:(\\)?|[A-z]:(\\[^\s\\]+)+)$/.test("C:")` returns `true` (Javascript)

Comment: there you go! looks good enough to me (I still think mine's simpler - but the better one is for the voters and OP to decide)

Comment: **Warning:** `[A-z]` is an error.  It matches several punctuation characters in addition to the letters.  If you want to match any ASCII letter, use `[A-Za-z]`, or `[a-z]` in case insensitive mode.

Comment: I meant to put that it _didn't_ match `C:\\` - but the back-tick quoting was messed up by the backslash - either way you fixed it

Comment: trying `if(!preg_match("/^(\\(\\[^\s\\]+)+|([A-Za-z]:(\\)?|[A-z]:(\\[^\s\\]+)+))$/", $drives)){echo 'error';}` actually echos out an error with this format \\home\place or C:\home\place or C:\ I was hoping to have a means of checking either or is that possible?

Comment: Remember you have to do this (at least in JavaScript): `"\\\\home\\place"` you have to escape the backslash.

Comment: wow, hmm then its gotta be something on my server side, currently I am working PHP side with things, and for some reason almost any one of these regex statments on for answers fail php side the one you just demo'ed is the the only one that doesnt actually break the script, but at the same time wont validate, and I can't figure it out currently. I may do it JS side for now to make the bosses happy and sort out the PHP side later, this is an internal SaaS product that people pay good money for so im not to worried about hackers at the moment.

Comment: Main reason I want it both sides is for the obvious though, as I'd like to validate on the front what I would on the back so theres absolutely no mix match anywhere down the road, but at the same time all bases get covered front to back

Comment: I have a space in my folder name in the UNC path. How do I handle this using the regular expression that you have stated ?

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work for me:

```
([A-Z]:|\\)(\\[a-z0-9]+)*
```

let me know if you've got any problems (undesirable or additional desired) matches

and to validate a WHOLE field, use:

```
^([A-Z]:|\\)(\\[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

*EDIT* a small revision was necessary to match ALL of your suggestions (my bad):

```
^([A-Z]:|\\)(\\$|\\[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: `[a-z0-9]` So I can't use characters other than a to z and 0 to 1? `ñç`?

Comment: not unless you add them to the character class, nope - I was thinking the more important part of it was making sure the `\\`'s were right, and additional characters would be easy enough to add.

Comment: not a clue - also depends upon WHAT you want to be able to match (for instance, `^([A-Z]:|\\)(\\$|\\\w+)*$` would probably be better than any in the answer at this point, and would probably work for any "English speaking" server - not sure how representative that is in a universal sense, but the question was asked in English and all the examples were in English... so...

Comment: :P `naïve` is an English word with the 2 dots above the `i`.

Comment: for SOME people, yes... but most will simply spell it with a normal `i`, but the real question is: is it something that many people would use in a network path or file system? Again - for the voters, OP, or anyone trying to implement this in their environment or application to determine for themselves.

Comment: I agree with you. Let the OP decides which one best fit his purpose.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12619/discussion-between-code-jockey-and-derek)

Answer (score 1):

For the first one I have:

```
^\\(\\[a-zA-Z_]\w*)+$
```

and the second one:

```
^[a-zA-Z]:(\\([a-zA-Z_]\w*)*)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

General case:

```
/^(\\\\\w+)(\\\w+)$/g   // matches \\comp, \\comp\xyz, \\comp\x\y\z\storage
```

Specific case:

```
/^([A-Z]:)(\\|\\\w+)*$/g  // matches C:\, X:, H:\path\to\folder
```

Comment: Maybe you're enclosing the regexp within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This will match UNC paths that start with an ip address and can handle spaces in the file / folder names. Also validates standard path formats e.g. C:\Users\User\some person\file.txt

```
/^((\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&(){}'._-]+([ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&(){}'._-]+)*)|([a-zA-Z]:))(\\[^ \\/:*?""<>|]+([ ]+[^ \\/:*?""<>|]+)*)*\\?$/
```

I modified the answers from:
[PHP Regex for matching a UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485091/php-regex-for-matching-a-unc-path/9485455#9485455)

and:
http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2285&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

See it in action at https://jsfiddle.net/megamania/q5ncy7t6/